# matrix addition giving wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, addition

I am from java background, I am learning python matrix operation. I have an assignment question to add two matrices manually I can't figure out the error in my logic. need help thank you

```
x = [[12,7,3],[4 ,5,6],[7 ,8,9]]  
y = [[5,8,1],[6,7,3],[4,5,9]]
row = len(x)
col = len(x[0])
ans = [[0] * col] * row
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
            ans[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j]
print()
print(ans)
```

output : 
[[11, 13, 18], [11, 13, 18], [11, 13, 18]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ans = [[0]*col]*row
```

This statement creates `row` number of objects, where each object is `[[0]*col]`. What this means is that, each "sub-list" in the list is pointing to the same list.

(More information about this behaviour here: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly))

You can verify that by checking the `id` values of `ans[0]`,`ans[1]` and so on:

```
>>> a = [[0]*col]*row
>>> 
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> id(a[0])
140336190913992
>>> id(a[1])
140336190913992
>>> id(a[2])
140336190913992
```

This means, if we set `a[0][1] = 10` (say), then EACH sub-list will have the the value `10` set. This is because all the lists point to the same list.

i.e.

```
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0]]
```

Now, how do we avoid this?
You can do so by initiliasing the `ans` list in a different way, as in:

```
b = [[0 for x in range(col)] for y in range(row)]
```

You can verify that all the sub-lists point to different addresses by using `id` again:

```
>>> id(b[0])
140336190512520
>>> id(b[1])
140336190765000
>>> id(b[2])
140336197031816
```

So now if you run your original program, you will get desired results.

TLDR; your modified program looks like this:

```
x = [[12,7,3],[4 ,5,6],[7 ,8,9]]  
y = [[5,8,1],[6,7,3],[4,5,9]]
row = len(x)
col = len(x[0])
ans = [[0 for x in range(col)] for y in range(row)]
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        ans[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j]
print(ans)
```